# Failing to access data from an array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, pass-by-reference

I am reading from a file (each line wolds 1 word) and putting each line into an array. However I'll get a segmentation fault whenever I try to access any element in the array. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
*update: added a while loop to grab the character one by one but I still get a segmentation fault

The pointer was made here:

```
char* ptr;
```

I passed it through the function as this:

```
fillDict(ptr,&size);
int fillDict(char* ptr,int *size)
```

And it reads the file and puts it into the array here:

```
    int i = -1;
    int numb;
    int wsize;
    while (fgets(word,30,file)!=NULL)
    {
            if (i==-1)
            {
                    if(word[strlen(word)-1]=='\n')
                    {
                            word[strlen(word)-1] = 0;
                    }
                    numb = atoi(word);
                    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));
            }
            else
            {
                    if(word[strlen(word)-1]=='\n')
                    {
                            word[strlen(word)-1] = 0;
                    }
                    wsize = wsize+strlen(word);
                    ptr = realloc(ptr,wsize);

                    int j = 0;                     //added from here
                    while(j<strlen(word)-1)
                    {
                            printf("%d\n",j);
                            ptr[j] = word[j];      //crashes here
                            j++;
                    }
                    ptr[j] = '\0';                 //to here

                    size++;
            }
            i++;
    }
    printf("%s",ptr[0]);           //but fails here
    fclose(file);
```

Comment: `ptr[i] = word;`  you are creating 1 dimensional array and trying to treat it as 2-dimensional.

Comment: Yes and also it looks like maybe the memory that `word` is pointing to is no longer valid as it goes out of scope outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jagannath mentioned, you are treating your `ptr` variable as a 2 dimensional array.

In reality, you allocate it as a simple buffer.

Schematically :

```
ptr = [][][][][][][][][][][][][][\0];
```

Then, you have a `word` which is also a simple buffer as follow :

```
word = [h][e][l][l][o][\0];
```

If you want to copy `word` to `ptr`, you need to iterate over both buffers and copy character by character as follow :

```
word = [h][e][l][l][o][\0];
        v  v  v  v  v
ptr  = [h][e][l][l][o][][][][][][][][][\0];
```

Otherwise, you can create an array of `word` by creating a 2 dimensional array.

```
 ptr = [|][|][][]...[\0]
        v  v
       [h][w]
       [e][o]
       [l][r]
       [l][l]
       [o][d]
       [0][0]
```

Finally, you have flaws in your code. Look at your `malloc(1)`... And your `wsize` is never initialized, so when you do `wsize = wsize+strlen(word);` the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows some fundamental misunderstanding about how pointers work. `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr+i)`. This makes no sense in the context of your code. It is therefore supposed to be a char but you are assigning a pointer to a char to it. And the printf that fails, well of course it's going to fail. it expects a pointer to a char but instead it gets whatever data is at the location `ptr` is pointing to and treats this as a pointer. This is likely to be a forbidden memory location hence the segfault. Even if it isn't, it is unlikely to reach a null terminating byte before it goes out of bound.